# CSS problems with our eBay custom HTML template

Tags: html, css, templates

we are building a template for our eBay listings.

eBay allows users to upload a description as HTML code and allows that code to link your external CSS files.

eBay displays the user's HTML code in an iframe, it looks like eBay calculates the height of your page on load and then and resizes the iframe according to that height.

Here is a link to one of our test listings in eBay's sandbox environment:
[http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=110097353751&ssPageName=ADME:L:LCA:US:1123#ht_692wt_1136](http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=110097353757&ssPageName=ADME%3aL%3aLCA%3aUS:1123#ht_500wt_1136)

In Chrome / Firefox there's a second scroll bar next to the listing.
In IE, the listings just covers eBay's footer which is even worse

I solved this issue once using CSS and i can't remember how.

I would really appreciate any help.

Here is our CSS code:
http://pastebin.com/aj4bffG9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this line from the `#StartDescription` rule in your CSS file:

```
height: 650px;
```

With this change, it works fine for me in Chrome/Firefox/Opera.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! I cant believe i didn't see that.

Comment: Perfectly valid question this.